# Ruby: String reconstruction algo, working only partially

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm

I'm working on a string reconstruction algorithm (a classic in dynamic programming examples, turning space less text into normal spaced text) in Ruby. **The code below is pure ruby, you can copy paste and start testing immediately**, it's working 80% of the time and tends to break, the larger the dictionary becomes. I've tested it with more then 80k words dictionaries and it works less good, about 70% of the time.

If there's a way to make it work 100% if the word is present in the dictionary, please show me.

*Here's the code: (it's well spaced and should be very readable)*

```
# Partially working string reconstruction algo in pure Ruby

# the dictionary
def dict(someWord)
  myArray = [" ", "best", "domain", "my", "successes", "image", "resizer", "high", "tech", "crime", "unit", "name", "edge", "times", "find", "a", "bargain", "free", "spirited", "style", "i", "command", "go", "direct", "to", "harness", "the", "force"]
  return !!(myArray.index(someWord))
end


# inspired by http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse202-a/lecture6-final.pdf

## Please uncomment the one you wanna use
#
# (all the words used are present in the dictionary above)
#
# working sentences
  x = ' ' + "harnesstheforce"
# x = ' ' + "hightechcrimeunit"
#
# non working sentences
# x = ' ' + "findabargain"
# x = ' ' + "icommand"

puts "Trying to reconstruct #{x}"

# useful variables we're going to use in our algo
n = x.length
k = Array.new(n)
s = Array.new(n)
breakpoints = Hash.new
validBreakpoints = Hash.new

begin

  # let's fill k
  for i in 0..n-1
    k[i] = i
  end

  # the core algo starts here
  s[0] = true
  for k in 1..n-1

    s[k] = false

    for j in 1..k
      if s[j-1] && dict(x[j..k])
        s[k] = true

        # using a hash is just a trick to not have duplicates
        breakpoints.store(k, true)
      end
    end

  end

  # debug
  puts "breakpoints: #{breakpoints.inspect} for #{x}"

  # let's create a valid break point vector

  i=1
  while i <= n-1 do

    # we choose the longest valid word
    breakpoints.keys.sort.each do |k|

      if i >= k
        next
      end

      # debug: when the algo breaks, it does so here and goes into an infinite loop
      #puts "x[#{i}..#{k}]: #{x[i..k]}"
      if dict(x[i..k])
        validBreakpoints[i] = k
      end
    end

    if validBreakpoints[i]
      i = validBreakpoints[i] + 1
    end

  end

  # debug
  puts "validBreakpoints: #{validBreakpoints.inspect} for #{x}"

  # we insert the spaces at the places defined by the valid breakpoints
  x = x.strip
  i = 0
  validBreakpoints.each_key do |key|
    validBreakpoints[key] = validBreakpoints[key] + i
    i += 1
  end

  validBreakpoints.each_value do |value|
    x.insert(value, ' ')
  end

  puts "Debug: x: #{x}"


  # we capture ctrl-c
rescue SignalException
  abort

# end of rescue
end
```

Comment: Hey guys, this is my first post, so bear with me. Can't wait to see what a solutions could be. This problem almost made me bang my head against the wall... :/

Comment: Yes, I've translate a pseudo code from an dynamic programming algo lecture... :) pdf can be found above. Also I'm new to Ruby, really trying to do my best here, please bear with me.

Comment: Don’t rescue from SignalException like you are. First because for a SIGINT (Ctrl C) you do exactly what happens anyway (exiting), second because there are many other signals all of which raise a SignalException and aren’t SIGINT.

Comment: Humm, you gotta point Andrew, but in my case, using Terminal on mac, Ctrl C doesn't do anything in that case unless I rescue like this... Weird I know. So I just found the quickest way to make it stop the program, if you have a better Exception to suggest for doing this, please share. By the way... I'm executing it as a Model class method in rails... With rails runner, perhaps this is why ctrl c doesn't respond unless I have a rescue in there..

Comment: @SphinxTechnologies: If you keep changing the question after it has been (partially) answered, the answers become quite worthless. The idea of SO is to store question-answer pairs for later reference.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your algorithm fails for strings containing single-character words. This is an off-by-one error. You are ignoring the breakpoints after such words, thus you end up with a word (`"abargain"`) not contained in your dictionary.

Change

```
   if i >= k
     next
   end
```

to

```
   if i > k
     next
   end
```

or more Ruby-like

```
   next if i > k
```

Note also that you are running into an endless loop whenever your string contains something which is not a word:

```
if validBreakpoints[i]        # will be false 
  i = validBreakpoints[i] + 1 # i not incremented, so start over at the same position
end
```

You better treat this as an error

```
return '<no parse>' unless validBreakpoints[i] # or throw if you are not in a function
i = validBreakpoints[i] + 1
```

The problem with `"inotifier"` is a deficiency of your algorithm. Always choosing the longest word is not good. In this case, the first "valid" breakpoint detected is after the `"in"` which leaves you the non-word `"otifier"`.

Comment: Man, wow, you spotted it immediately ! I fixed this off-by-one error like you suggested, ruby style :) it's much better now, it's works around 90% of the time, but still brake for some case, let me include such examples.

Comment: Absolutely man... I was looking for a way to treat this problem, was using a timeout loop. That's much better !

Comment: Ok undur, I've implemented your fixes ! Really much much better now... :-) But i've found an example were it still breaks... with a two words sentence like ("inotifier")... I've set it up in the code above for immediate testing.

Comment: Hmmm... I see ! :) So I must find a way to adapt the strategy if the first one fails. If "longest word" fails, I move to "first valid word". I'll try implementing that. You're a life saver, God bless you man.

Comment: Undur, I solved the ("inotifier") problem, see above. It's now so much better. But it's still breaks let's say with ("themagicmall") or ("intheminute"). How to make my fix work for those too ? :/ I honestly think I don't have enough brain power to calculate the solution.