# The best String reconstruction algorithm out there ? (Best as in 'most accurate')

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I've been searching and testing all kinds of **string reconstruction algorithm** i.e. reconstructing spaceless text into normal text.

My result posted here [Solution working partially in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879340/ruby-string-reconstruction-algo-working-only-partially), is working at **90% reconstruction for 2 or 3 words sentences, with a complete dictionary**. But I can't get it to run better then this !

I think my algorithm inspired from [dynamic programming](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse202-a/lecture6-final.pdf) is bad and contains a lot of patch work.

*Can you propose another algorithm (in pseudo-code) that would work foolproof with a complete dictionary ?*

Comment: Please give more detail, and/or an example problem and solution. Are you wanting to taking a string of letters containing no space characters and attempt to split them into words contained in some master list of words (e.g. a list of English words)?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: 100% success rate via brute force -- going through all permutation.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem guys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879340/ruby-string-reconstruction-algo-working-only-partially, make it work at 100%. I implement this dynamic programming algo http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse202-a/lecture6-final.pdf but it's not complete, they don't explain how to do the final 'reconstruction part'. So I'm trying stuff, but am not successful at 100% yet. Please take a look at the lecture and you'll see that the algo it's not complete. And I've looked everywhere, all the teachers drop this last part... :/

Comment: So is it doing a brute force algo the only solution ? No other way ?

Comment: Brute force can't work, because some words are compound words. For example, it is not a foregone conclusion that brute force would correctly insert spaces in this sentence, as aforementioned.

Answer (score 6):

You need more than just a dictionary, because you can have multiple possible phrases from the same spaceless string. For example, "themessobig" could be "the mess so big" or "themes so big" or "the mes so big", etc.

Those are all valid possibilities, but some are far more likely than others. Thus what you want to do is pick the most likely one given how the language is actually used. For this you need a huge corpus of text along with some NLP algorithms. Probably the most simple one is to count how likely a word is to occur after another word. So for "the mess so big", it's likelihood would be:

```
P(the | <START>) * P(mess | the) * P(so | mess) * P(big | so)
```

For "themes so big", the likelihood would be:

```
P(themes | <START>) * P(so | themes) * P(big | so)
```

Then you can pick the most likely of the possibilities. You can also construct triplets instead of tuples (e.g. `P(so | the + mess)`) which will require a bigger corpus to be effective.

This won't be foolproof but you can get better and better at it by having better corpuses or tweaking the algorithm.

Comment: Man that's awesome ! You answered a great problem I may have faced in the future. Thanks so much for that. I think my question could have been clearer. Let's say I want to reconstruct "themagicmall"... If I go with a longest valid word startegy... I get "them agic mall".. Not good. If I go with the shortest valid word I get "the ma ..." Not good cause "ma" is a valid word... So how to make an algo that picks "the magic mall"... making the whole sentence valid ?

Comment: I know how to get the possible breakpoints... that's easy... and well explained here http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi12/cse202-a/lecture6-final.pdf but how to reconstruct a correct sentences with this possible breakpoints vector ?

Comment: I imagine NLTK would help here.

Comment: @Marcin and Claudiu, that's a breakthrough... So that's a NLP problem huh ? and Could easily be solved with NLP toolkits ? What would be the name of such functions ?

Comment: NLTK is a python toolkit for natural language processing. There are many other such toolkits if you google them. This is an active research area.

Answer (score 0):

With an unigram language model, which is essentially word frequencies,
it is possible to find the most probable segmentation of a string.

[Example code from Russell & Norvig (2003, p. 837)](http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/text.py) (look for the function viterbi_segment)